# Import cmocka library in Bazel Build

Tags: embedded, bazel, bazel-rules, cmocka

I'm using cmocka with Bazel and I want to import cmocka library in my test files (for c embedded code) like <cmocka.h> but I'm always getting:  cmocka.h: No such file or directory.

my Build is:

```
cc_library(
    name = "mock",
    srcs = ["mock_i2c.c"],
    deps = [":src"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkstatic = True,
    copts = ["-I test/cmocka/include"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [includes](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.includes) attribute for that case, also you need to add your headers to `hdrs` attribute:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "mock",
    srcs = ["mock_i2c.c"],
    deps = [":src"],
    hdrs = glob(["test/cmocka/include/**/*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkstatic = True,
    includes= ["test/cmocka/include"],
)
```

Comment: because I'm working in src dir and my cmocka is in test dir.

Comment: You need to add also `hdrs` attribute, i have updated the answer. If it is not working, then please show your project topology, because it is hard to guess the solution

Comment: --src:  hello.c
          Build
--test: test.c
          Build
          cmoka:
                     include:
                                 cmocka.h

Comment: in the home dir, there are test and src.
In src: mock_i2c.c and Build.
In test: test.c Build and cmocka.

Comment: Create separate library for cmocka `cc_library(name="cmocka", hdrs=["cmocka.h"], includes=["."])` in `test/cmocka/BUILD` file, then add that library as dependency to the `mock` target